# Is there any way to write with less "nesting"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The problem is a homework problem. I think I solved it but I'm wondering is it the best solution? The problem is to take a list and run through it to see if it contains a specific subsequence: 007. Here subsequence is used in the mathematical sense (so 0110227 *does* contain 007 and returns True).

```py
def spy_game(nums):
    if 0 in nums:
        a_1=nums.index(0)
        nums_1=nums[a_1+1:]
        if 0 in nums_1:
            a_2=nums_1.index(0)
            if 7 in nums[a_2+1:]:
                return True 
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    else: 
        return False
```

Comment: The `else: return False` are un-needed, just a `return False` at the bottom will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: The 3 last else are unecessary, you can just replace them by a single return False. As there's only 1 way to return True, anything else would return False :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by negating your test condition so you can simply return early. The last test doesn't require an `if` statement at all, since by that point the result of the condition is the return value of the function.

```
def spy_game(nums):
    if 0 not in nums:
        return False

    a_1 = nums.index(0)
    nums_1 = nums[a_1+1:]

    if 0 not in nums_1:
        return False

    a_2 = nums_1.index(0)
    return 7 in nums[a_2+1:]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you negate your inclusion conditions you can return early rather than introducing further nesting.

```
def spy_game(nums):
    if 0 not in nums:
        return False
    a_1 = nums.index(0)
    num_1 = nums[a_1+1:]
    if 0 not in nums_1:
        return False
    a_2 = nums_1.index(0)
    return 7 in nums_1[a_2+1:]
```

You can also write this without creating any copies of the list by using the [`start`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) parameter to the index method, which will tell the index method the index at which to start searching for the element. This code looks different but achieves the same thing and may be easier to maintain for you.

```
def spy_game(nums):
    try:
        start = 0
        for n in [0, 0, 7]:
            start = nums.index(n, start)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to design your functions so that they don't depend on the specific input. For example:

```
def contains_anywhere(s, search):
    i = 0
    for c in search:
        try:
            i = s.index(c, i) + 1
        except ValueError:
            return False
    return True

ok = contains_anywhere([0,1,1,0,2,2,7,2], [0,0,7])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option, I personally don't see an issue with the nesting here.

This is shortening it up:

```
def spy_game(nums):
    if 0 in nums:
        nums_1 = nums[nums.index(0)+1:]
        if 0 in nums_1:
            if 7 in nums[nums_1.index(0)+1:]:
                return True
    return False
```

output:

```
>>> spy_game([1,0,7])
False
>>> spy_game([0,1,7])
False
>>> spy_game([1,0,1])
False
>>> spy_game([0,0,7])
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code hides what you are trying to do. Try this alternative. even though it still has 3 levels of nesting, it is clearer about what it is doing:

```
def spy_game(nums):
    search_for = [x for x in "007"]
    for n in nums:
        if not search_for:  # found everything we were looking for
            return True
        if n == search_for[0]:  # found the next item
            search_for.pop(0)
return False
```

Comment: If the requirement is a list of numbers, this doesn't compare numbers to strings properly (fixed with `search_for = [int(x) for x in "007"]`) and the loop breaks before returning `True` on cases like `[0,0,7]`, moving the `if not search_for:` check under the `pop` fixes this, but we're back to 3 layers of nesting. I do agree, this makes the intention of the function clearer.